# Maven Spring-boot:start doesnt work when trying to run integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Integration Test Issues in Spring Project with Maven

I am working on a Spring project and encountering issues while trying to run integration tests using Maven's verify goal. Initially, I faced a timeout error:

```
  `Spring application did not start before the configured timeout (30000ms)`
```

In an attempt to resolve this, I added the following configuration:

```
   `<wait>90000</wait>`
```

However, after making this change, a new issue has surfaced:

````
  ```
     AM com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientCommunicatorAdmin$Checker run
     WARNING: Failed to check connection: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
     com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ClientCommunicatorAdmin$Checker run
      WARNING: stopping
   ```
````

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzhks.png)
[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMRtQ.png)